# Javascript: Is there a way to get the filename of the dragged-in file?

Tags: javascript, drag-and-drop, filenames

When user drags in a file, is there a way in Javascript to detect its filename onDragEnter (not after it's uploaded)?

Comment: Are you using any sort of file uploader library?

Comment: Trying out this one: https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload

Answer (score 1):

Not every browser supports dragging files to a file input (FF4 on OS X certainly doesn't), but you *can* check the value of the file input on `change` event, which should provide a uniform result across browsers.

Depending on the browser, you can check the value of

```
<input type="file" id="foo" />
```

like so:

```
// vanilla JS
var filename = document.getElementById('foo').value;

// jQuery
var filename = $('#foo').val();
```

You'd do this inside of a `change` listener, like so (example for jQuery in jsFiddle below):

```
function alertFileName()
{
    alert(this.value);
}

var input = document.getElementById('foo');

// not IE friendly; use `attachEvent` instead
input.addEventListener('change', alertFilename, false);
```

If you upload a file named `bar.txt`, `filename` will be:

- `'C:\fakepath\bar.txt'` (Chrome)
- `'bar.txt'` (Firefox 4, Safari)
- ??? (IE)

I am not set up to test IE at present; feel free to [try it yourself](http://jsfiddle.net/mattball/hzANK/).

Comment: I think Safari does the same too. It must be a WebKit thing.

Comment: Nope, Safari matches FF4. It would also be a decidedly un-Mac-like thing for Apple's browser to return Windows-like file paths

Comment: Hmm, don't know why I thought that then. It's a bit weird that Chrome on OS X still returns a Windows style path.